# Can I make a Rainmeter widget that fetches the nearest/town or city via HTML5 geolocation?

Tags: html, geolocation, widget

I'm trying to build a Rainmeter widget that fetches the nearest town to the user and displays it onscreen. I'm currently trying to use the webparser function and [this website](http://locationdetection.mobi/), but it doesn't seem to be working. The code I've adapted from the example on the Rainmeter website is below - any ideas?

```
[Rainmeter]
Author=Rainmeter staff
Update=1000

;[WEBSITE MEASURES]===============================

[MeasureWebsite]
Measure=Plugin
Plugin=WebParser
UpdateRate=1800
URL=http://locationdetection.mobi/
RegExp="(?siU)<span style="color:white;">town_city:</span> <b>"(.*)"</b>.*"

[MeasureTown]
Measure=Plugin
Plugin=WebParser
Url=[MeasureWebsite]
StringIndex=1

;[DISPLAY METERS]==================================

[TextStyle]
X=2
Y=17
FontFace=Segoe UI
FontSize=32
FontColor=#454442
StringStyle=Bold
Antialias=1

[MeterTown]
MeasureName=MeasureTown
Meter=String
MeterStyle=TextStyle
Y=2
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's too late but... your URL doesn't seem to contain any town_city information... at least not in the source code.

Rainmeter reads the raw HTML code from the URL you give to it and processes it through the provided RegEx. Without proper information in the website you can never get it to work.